# Product of class sums

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, group-rings

Let $C_i$ be the conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$. Consider the class sums $z_i=\sum_{g\in C_i} g$. It is well known that ${z_i}$ form a basis of the center of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$. How can we show that $z_iz_j$ is a $\mathbb{N}$ linear combinations of the $z_i$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the background of that question? Maybe any relations to the character and representation theory of the group it may have..?

Comment: Well, a product of things in the center is in the center, and everything in the center is expressible as a linear combination of those thingies as you just said, so...

Comment: @whacka then it can be expressed as a $\mathbb{C}$ linear combination, that is what it says, nothing about $\mathbb{N}$ linear combination.

Comment: Fair enough, although one easily gets $\Bbb Z$-linear combinations by just considering $\Bbb Z[G]$ instead of $\Bbb C[G]$.

Comment: $z_i$ form a basis of center of $\mathbb{C}G$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. What do you mean considering $\mathbb{Z}[G]$?

Comment: I mean the class sums form a $\Bbb Z$-basis for the center of the integral group ring $\Bbb Z[G]$. The proof is the exact same: show that if $x$ is in the center then the coefficient of $g$ and $h$ within $x$ must be equal if $g\sim h$. (Say $g=\sigma h\sigma^{-1}$ and then equate coefficients from the equality $\sigma x\sigma^{-1}=x$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the proof that the class sums form a $\Bbb C$-basis for the group algebra $\Bbb C[G]$. Say that

$$x\in Z(\Bbb C[G]), \qquad x=\sum_{g\in G}a(g)g.$$

(Think of the coefficients $a(g)$ as a function $a:G\to\Bbb C$.) Then for any $\sigma\in G$ we have

$$\sigma x\sigma^{-1}=\sum_{g\in G}a(g)\sigma g\sigma^{-1}=\sum_{g\in G}a(\sigma^{-1}g\sigma) g.$$

But since $x$ is central, we know $x=\sigma x\sigma^{-1}$. Comparing coefficients below,

$$\sum_{g\in G}a(g)g=\sum_{g\in G}a(\sigma^{-1} g\sigma)g$$

we find $a(g)=a(\sigma^{-1}g\sigma)$ for all $g,\sigma\in G$, i.e. $a$ is a class function. Thus $a(C)$ makes sense, where we denote by $C$ a conjugacy class of $G$, and so as $C$ ranges over classes we have

$$x=\sum_C a(C)\sum_{g\in C}g.$$

Conversely, class sums are invariant under conjugation by $G$, so any class sum or combination of class sums commutes with any $g\in G$, and hence commutes with every element of $\Bbb C[G]$.

Now if $x,y\in Z(\Bbb C[G])$ then so is $xy$. Therefore if $x$ and $y$ are two class sums, $xy$ must be a $\Bbb C$-linear combination of class sums. But how do we get that it's an $\Bbb N$-linear combination?

Consider instead the [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) $\Bbb N[G]$ (note that our $\Bbb N$ must contain $0$; think about abelian groups $G$ to see this). It is comprised of $\Bbb N$-linear combinations of elements of $G$, with the same obvious rules for addition and multiplication, but this time there aren't additive inverses. The same argument that is written above shows every element of the center $Z(\Bbb N[G])$ (the elements that commute with everything else) are $\Bbb N$-linear combinations of class sums. Clearly the product of any two central elements is central, so the product of class sums must be an $\Bbb N$-linear combination of class sums!

This shows that all of our already-present logic and understanding is perfectly sufficient for the problem at hand, and no new thinking is necessary. One can also give a counting interpretation to the coefficients. If $z_\Gamma=\sum_{g\in \Gamma}g$ denote class sums, and $[g]$ denotes the conjugacy class of an element $g\in G$, then for any three elements $a,b,c\in G$ the coefficient of $z_{[c]}$ in the expansion of the product $z_{[a]}z_{[b]}$ equals $\#\{(x,y)\in G^2:x\sim a,y\sim b,xy=c\}$. Indeed in order to count such a thing with generatingfunctionological thinking, one would naturally look for the coefficient of $c$ in the expansion of $(\sum_{x\sim a}x)(\sum_{y\sim b}y)$!

Comment: Aha, so the point is that because _there is_ a basis of $Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$ that lives in $\mathbb{N}[G]$, the rest should follow...

Comment: Another idea is that an element of $Z(\Bbb C[G])$ is an $\Bbb N$-linear combination of class sums iff it is an $\Bbb N$-linear combination of group elements. Then since class sums are in $\Bbb N[G]$ which is closed under multiplication, products of class sums are $\Bbb N$-linear combinations of group elements, and so the result follows. This avoids mentioning semirings, at the cost of extra work (when instead one could simply transplant the original logic into the semiring setting at no extra cost).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not that difficult if you expand the product $z_iz_j$... Then, say you have an element $gh$ in that product with $g\in C_i$ and $h\in C_j$. If we show that all the elements in its conjugacy class appear in the expansion of $z_iz_j$ (the correct number of times), we are done...

Such an element, would be $t^{-1}ght=t^{-1}gt\cdot t^{-1}ht$ which should also appear in $z_iz_j$ since $t^{-1}gt\in C_i$ and $t^{-1}ht\in C_j$.

Evenmore it is not difficult to check that if $gh$ appears many times in the expansion (say because $gh=g'h'$), then $t^{-1}ght$ should appear as many times as well...

---

Edit: Let me elaborate on that last part:

Say $gh=g_2h_2=\cdots=g_kh_k$ where all the factorizations are different, that is, $gh$ appears $k$-many times in the expansion. Now consider a $t\in G$ such that $t^{-1}ght\neq gh$. We'll show that $t^{-1}ght$ should appear at least $k$ times in the expansion as well (this should be enough, because by symmetry we could apply the same argument for $gh$ appearing more times...).

Of course, we have $t^{-1}ght=t^{-1}g_2h_2t=\cdots=t^{-1}g_kh_kt$. Moreover, each of these products can be written as $t^{-1}g_ih_it=t^{-1}g_it\cdot t^{-1}h_it$. Now, any time that at least one of the pairs $(t^{-1}g_it,t^{-1}g_jt)$ and $(t^{-1}h_it,t^{-1}h_jt)$ contains different elements, both $t^{-1}g_ih_it$ and $t^{-1}g_jh_jt$ appear in the decomposition. But of course, if the two pairs contained the exact same elements, we would have $g_i=g_j$ and $h_i=h_j$, so we wouldn't have gotten two *different* factorizations of $gh$ to start with...

---

Edit: As far as the coefficients go, the enumerative interpretation below by whacka is both correct and fruiful, as there is a lot of research about counting factorizations of group elements. However in general, it is very difficult to get a formula for the coefficient of $z_t$.

One reason for that is that apart from the classical Coxeter groups (types A,B,C,D...) and few other examples, we don't even have a consistent way to *index* the conjugacy classes of a group.

Moreover, even in the Symmetric group case, where the conjugacy classes have nice combinorial descriptions, we only have partial results. However the theory there is very beautiful and factorizations are connected to particular graphs embedded on surfaces, topologically distinct holomorphic functions, and of course Representation theory.

You can check out this nice [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669800904098) by Goulden and Jackson, and its many references, for *part* of the Symmetric group case...

Comment: the idea is more or less clear, thanks. What will be the coefficient of each $z_t$ in the above decomposition of $z_iz_j$?

Comment: Give me some time and I will accept your answer. I am not completely satisfied. Still thinking what the coefficients will be.

Comment: @user114539 See my edit above